# MVC 5 and WebApi2 using OWIN OAuth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am creating an application that will use MVC 5 to serve the initial layout, views, scripts, etc. and then I am using WebApi2 to serve data to the UI.

I want to use the OWIN OAuth bits for Authentication on the WebApi.

The WebApi lives in a DLL and the MVC 5 app is a Web Application.

I have referenced [this article](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) for the OAuth WebApi bits.

How do I setup the WebApi to run in the MVC 5 application and use the OWIN Startup class?

Or is this not possible?

Comment: is your question about how to make WebAPI and a traditional MVC 5 app share code and routes?

Comment: No, more on how to use OAuth for the WebApi using OWIN while hosting the two together.

Comment: I guess I'm still confused.  what does using the OAuth provider with OWIN have to do with them being hosted together?

Comment: That is what I am trying to make work... I think I am getting close and will update the question if I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to check the VS 2013 Web API template (Web API and MVC core dependency) but with individual accounts checked as [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L14Jz.png), I believe you are missing adding those both lines in class WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

You need to suppress the default authentication (Forms Auth) then add the bearer authentication only for Web API.